# Is there any way to push the notification to all the user at once in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I wanted to know if there is any way to send push notifications to all users using Expo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) with react-native to add instant push notification on your app

Expo has a nice documentation on how to implement it [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-fcm)

Comment: However this leaves the iOS users out in the cold...

Alas it seems that there is no way to do this in a platform-independent way because there is no way to do it on iOS without having all the device tokens